# Keep activity on when screen is off

Tags: android, android-activity

I got a service that start a new activity, while screen is off. 
I want the activity to stay on paused mode, and not get to the stopped mode.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to do this ?

Comment: Share what you are trying to achieve, maybe we will be able to provide some alternate solution.

Answer (score 7):

No.  You don't have control over the Activity lifecycle.  Any processes that you need to run while the screen is off must be executed in a `Service`.  You must rebuild the application state whenever the screen is turned back on.  Always assume the `Activity` can be wiped from memory at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the `onDestroy()` method, and each OS version handles how an application is "killed" differently.

The [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) makes reference to an application being in a “killable” state.  While Android tries to keep the process of an application resident even after it has exited (i.e. after `onDestroy`), it does need to be able to kill these processes in low-resource situations to reclaim memory.  **The states in which an application is killable differ per OS version**.  On all versions of Android, applications that have returned from `onStop` or `onDestroy` are silently killable.  On versions of Android prior to Honeycomb, applications that had returned from `onPause` were also killable.  Being killable simple means that Android reserves the right to terminate your application’s process at any time without running even another instruction of your app’s code.  In other words, if you have any state that must be recoverable (such as a player’s game progress, items, awards, etc) you must save those to persistent storage no later than the last callback before entering a killable state.

In addition, while applications can run native threads even when they are in a killable 
state and even post-`onDestroy`, this is to be avoided, since the process kill will also kill those threads.  This could cause all manner of corruption and shutdown issues.

[Source](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/mobile/files/AndroidLifecycleAppNote_v100.pdf)

Comment: but i want my activity to be shown when screen is on as fast as i can

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to do that through `onPause()` and `onResume()` but understand that `onDestroy()` could be called when the screen is off.

Comment: Also it's not certain onDestroy() [always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called) will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. it will be killed anyway.
but you can use a `Service` to receive Broadcast of `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and **relaunch** activity from Service.
to restart your Activity from service check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this. Your app is tied to the Activity lifecycle, and has to break down/restore the Activities to work with the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly now what you mean with paused mode or stopped mode. If you mean that the cpu keep wake up take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

With partial_wake_look you can have a long running AsyncTask for example also when the screen is of. Dont't forget to release the wakelook.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this? Maybe best solution is to run it as a service as suggested by @DeeV. However, depending of what you need to do, this could help:

Ask Android to notify you when screen is turned on (and off if required). So your activity can be resumed and started immediately and you can perform any action.

To do that:

- Create a class which extends Application
- Register it in your Manifest:

  In public void onCreate() {..., add this:

  IntentFilter ioff = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

  IntentFilter ion = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

  ```
      broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              String action = intent.getAction();

              if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action)) {
                  //TODO
              } else {
                  //TODO
              }
          }
      };

      context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, ioff);
      context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, ion);
  ```

  - in public void onTerminate() {..., add this:

`if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }`

Comment: Check this link: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using this stuff, the problem is that the screen on reacts really slow, so I'm working with the screen of, and try to keep me alive.

Answer (score 0):

Lame hack would be to call onPause() method inside onStop() of activity