# How can I manage OnApp exit event and do something before app closes?

Tags: android, events, exit

I have to send some requests to my server before app exits.

But as my app close all asynctasks are killed and the requests aren't being sent to my web service.

Comment: Try on terminate () in Application class

Comment: Can you please specify better what you mean for 'app exits'? You mean all activities are destroyed?

Comment: @Asthme : it's not works.

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli : no, just wanna find out when my app closes so that i can have some communication with web.

Comment: Write before super. On terminate();

Comment: @Asthme : am i right? you say i put onTerminate in my application class and write my code before it's super. but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Asthme It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solve this by put exit function in my main activity and passing and extra so it can find out I open it for closing whole app. this is very good solution.

call main activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(G.currentActivity, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.putExtra("isExit", true);
```

and get extra like this:

```
private void getExtras() {
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
if (myIntent.getBooleanExtra("isExit", false)) {
    showExitDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }
  }
```

**Update:**
It can be handled better with Eventbus. I have main activity that loads fragments with ChangePageEventMessage event that contains eventType that Enum.

```
public onEvent(ChangePageEventMessage event){
    switch(event.getType()){
       case appExit: dosomething();
                     System.exit(0);
                     break;
       case detail:
.
.
.
.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a YourBasicActivity and override its `OnPause()` method and extend every Activity from YourBasicActivity

[Run code when Android app is closed/sent to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593115/run-code-when-android-app-is-closed-sent-to-background)

You can also try `onTaskRemoved`

[How to detect application exit on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406508/how-to-detect-application-exit-on-android)

Comment: unfortunately it works on any of my activities finishes. I like to do on whole app exit.  what is the solution?

Comment: in baseActivity or in Application?

Comment: there is no background service to add onTaskRemoved