# How to detect if whole application is close in android

Tags: java, android

Some times application be closed by pressing home button and onDestroy() doesn't call. I want to call a method when whole application is closed and I'm not going to call my method in all activities's onDestroy().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect exit of an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298795/is-it-possible-to-detect-exit-of-an-application)

Comment: May be an extra service will do the trick, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406508/how-to-detect-application-exit-on-android create and override the method.!

Comment: you can check if the process is alive or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implements LifecycleObserver inside appication class an then use as blow:

```
public class App extends Application implements LifecycleObserver{

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onMoveToForeground() {


    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onMoveToBackground() {

    }
}
```

Also can use other events like Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY or ON_CREATE

Comment: Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY is not getting called.

Answer (score -1):

Application does not close on home button press.But it goes in background.

When you Application goes in background(Your front activity goes in background) it calls onStop() Method(Activity is not visible now).So you should do all stuff here.

There is no such call back  the Application class. Which tell you that application is destroyed.
If you want to fire an event when application is fully closed.You should check your application's activity stack.If it does not have any activity than your application is closed. You should check it from a service.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to detect if my app is showing now or is destroyed or is running in background

Comment: onStop means that particular activity is in the background, would be called when app goes in background, but also a lot of other situations (another acitivity in app is opened, etc.).  So onStop doesn't really address this person's issue.

Comment: @Bourne I have already mentioned in my answer that there is No way to detect that your application is completely closed. You can do some tricks to get closer result for that problem