# end application doesn't call on destroy

Tags: java, android, ondestroy

when i press end button on my samsumsung galaxy s2 it doesn't call onDestroy method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
Toast.makeText(context, "destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: what is the "end" button

Comment: end button under active apps menu it is on the right of the application  & can be used to exit the application

Answer (score 6):

Its not necessary that it would be called when the activity is finishing. `onPause` is sure to be called. If you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) of `onDestroy`, it says:

`Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here.`

If you see this question [Activity OnDestroy never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called) , the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4449988/1306419) says:

`onDestroy()` is called only when system is low on resources(memory, cpu time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application or when somebody calls finish() on your activity.

So, when you press that button to exit the application, its not necessary that `onDestroy` will be called.

Comment: I've spent hours analyzing thread interactions because `onDestroy()` was not always called when swiping my (native) activity to death from within the task switcher. Sometimes it was called, but most of the time it didn't so I suspected a deadlock\race somewhere in my code. Quite brutal to send a SIGKILL immediately, without even _trying_ to shut an activity down elegantly. Strangely enough, using ART instead of Dalvik appears to increase the frequency of `onDestroy()` calls. First time I've spent hours trying to fix a bug that is literally a feature..