# Why onDestroy inActivity A not being called after a call to finish() in ActivityB

Tags: android, android-activity

The next process is simple to understand and to reproduce but leads to a bug:

- activityA starts an activityB in its `onCreate()` method
- activityB is created and I call `finish()` in its onResume() method
- activityB `onDestroy()` is called
- activityA `onResume()` is called
- and here in activityA, I click a menu button to call `finish()` - or press the back key.
- activityA is removed but `onDestroy()` is NOT called and A is still living ( adb shell dumpsys 'myPackageName' indicates too many living Activities )

Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="gleroy.com.algo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="gleroy.com.algo.activity.FakeA"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name="gleroy.com.algo.activity.FakeB"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Activity A :

```
public class FakeA extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = FakeA.class.getCanonicalName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate, taskId :" + getTaskId());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(FakeA.this, FakeB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.stop_session_menu_item:
                /* stop and quit */
                finish();
                return false;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Activity B :

```
public class FakeB extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = FakeB.class.getCanonicalName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate, taskId :"+getTaskId());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume, isFinishing :" + isFinishing());
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Activity A is started from MainActivity which contains a simple button :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FakeA.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

So I know that we can't be sure that `onDestroy()` is gonna be called but here my ActivityA is clearly leaking.

Also I observed that if I use a `Timer` and `TimerTask` to delay `startActivity` in ActivityA or `finish()` in ActivityB then I don't have this bug anymore.

Here are the events :

- FakeA onCreate, taskId :154
- FakeA onResume
- FakeA onPause, isFinishing : false
- FakeB onCreate, taskId :154
- FakeB onResume, isFinishing :false
- FakeA onResume
- FakeB onDestroy
- call finish or press back key : FakeA onPause, isFinishing : true

Comment: return true in onOptionsItemSelected() and check

Comment: false or true doesn't change anything

Comment: you call startActivity(B) in A.onResume()? what is purpose of that strange UX?

Comment: Your code is starting activityB in onCreate(), not onResume(). Which do you mean?

Comment: @CPUTerminator He means, that his AcitivityA starts the `onResume()` method of ActivityB

Comment: @user1570693 Is your `onPause()` of your FakeA getting called?

Comment: - it doesn't matter where I start activityB ( onResume or onCreate of activityA )
- yes onPause of ActivityA is called

Comment: @user1570693 ok this could be your system's fault, add `+ isFinishing()` to your Log inside your `onPause()` of your FakeA, see if it returns true,

Comment: I think since FakeB onDestroy is called after FakeA onResume(), onDestroy of FakeA is not called. If you give delay, then FakeA onResume gets called after FakeB onDestroy, hence at that time FakeA onDestroy gets called.

Comment: well probably but then it is still very strange that I must add a kind of delay ( how much ? ) to handle this case properly.

Comment: @user1570693 Sufficient enough to get FakeA onResume called after FakeB onDestroy.

Comment: Good and clear question - I have had something similar happen.

Answer (score 1):

In place of `finish()` try `finishAffinity()`.
As far as i know:
`finish()` just destroys the current live `Activity`
while, `finishAffinity()` destroys all active `Activities`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution was simply to detect whether or not it is useful to start Activity FakeB.