# OnCreate runs after back button is pressed

Tags: android

I am trying to understand what happens under the hood when the user presses on back and I did not overwrite `onOptionsItemSelected`.

I have the following scenario:

1. Activity A with `intent.putExtra("abc", "abc");`
2. Activity B with `getIntent()` in `onCreate()`
3. Activity C

What exactly happens when the user clicks back in activity C?

If I don't overwrite the back button, pressing back will produce a nullException on the getIntent line. Why? It's in `onCreate()` not in `onStart()`.

If I use `onSaveInstanceState` the bundle is always empty. This leads me to assume that back is creating a new instance of the Activity. Why? It should just finish itself.

If I overwrite the back button with `finish()` it no longer crashes but I thought the default behavior of back is to run `finish()`.

**EDIT with more details:**

I put a toast in each of the lifecycle methods and I found out that Activity B calls on destroy **after** I press back on Activity C. This makes no sense to me!

**Manifest:**

*Activity A*

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

*Activity B*

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MenuActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/menu_title"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

*Activity C*

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.OptionActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/option_title"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MenuActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: WHat happens when user clicks back in activity C depends on if there was a "finish()" called from Activity B before calling Activity C

Comment: There is no `finish()` in activity B which is why I don't get it.

Comment: Can we see your code pls? And the log as well.

Comment: I have no code in Activity C that's the whole point I can write code to prevent the crash but I want to understand why I have to. I do not overwrite the back button at all. The line that causes the crash is in Activity B: `this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(STATE_REST)` and the activity shows a nullException because it's being recreated and there is no intent. My question is why does Activity B get destroyed when I click back on Activity C.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file? It may be helpful to see how you specified 'Activity B' there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Activity B get destroyed when I click back on Activity C ?

Are you using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` for intent before starting your activity. It will clear the `backstack` and when you press back, the activity will be recreated.

**UPDATE:**

Don't rely on the call for `onDestroy()` as it may or may not be called on back button press.
However it is guaranteed to be called on a call to `finish()` but is not surely gets called on a back button press.

[Activity OnDestroy never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called)

Comment: No I do not but that would indeed call `onDestroy()`.

Comment: You mean that the `onDestroy()` method is not called for Activity C but called for Activity B ?

Comment: It's also called (correctly) for C but it should not be called for B.

Comment: Don't rely on the call for onDestroy() as it may or may not be called on back button press. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called

Comment: I'm not relying on it. I am saying it should not be called when I hit back but for some reason it is. Always! This should not happen per the documentation as it should only be called when the system needs the space.

Comment: No guarantee. Why it should not be called when you hit back button. The system may still call it. Did you checked other devices or systems with enough space ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56718/discussion-between-mikael-and-ved-prakash).