# onDestroy never called

Tags: android, ondestroy

I have updated the latest Android Studio and created a new Blank Project. I added the following code to the MainActivity.java file, but onDestroy() is never called. Is there any way to get destroy event?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.edevshop.destroy">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It is getting called.

Comment: call `onFinish()` instant of `onDestroy()`

Comment: show manifest settings

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called

Comment: if it not getting called its means you activity is still out there.

Answer (score 0):

just check it out and modify your `onDestroy()` method as below:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("TAG", "Yay.. onDestroy called!");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now... Run App > Open LOGCAT > close App (By pressing BACK button)
You'll see a LOG.

Comment: Thanks, it works but not always as described Sanjay Kakadiya.