# How to measure how much time my user spent in my app and send it to Firebase Events

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, android-lifecycle, firebase-analytics

Okay the question is pretty simple. The hard part has been that my app features gallery and camera functionality, that means that OnStop and OnResume trigger when technically the user is using the app, but that isn't that much of an issue (I can ignore the time they spend using the those features). The issue is when do I log the event? I tried logging it onDestroy but that never seems to be happening. Single activity approach, so as long the activity is up and running that how long the user was using the app.

Any suggestion is welcomed

I am currently using this (never getting logged)

```
    override fun onResume() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        timeSpent += System.currentTimeMillis().minus(startTime)
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        firebaseEventManager.logTimeSpentInApp(timeSpent)
        Timber.d("On Destroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Comment: aren't these just events you can already get from firebase analytics ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I dont think you can get how much time has spent in the app. There isn't a built in event for that

Comment: You need to know how much time the user has the app open, or how much time it interacts with Firebase? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo how much time he spends in the app, and then send that data to Firebase Events.

Comment: So you only have a single activity in your entire app, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, it is. I am wondering if on destroy is a viable place to log the time spent

Comment: No, it's not. [onDestroy is not always called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called).

Comment: @AlexMamo That's great to know, is there any alternative to my problem? Seems like a rather common usecase